# maven does not detect tests from the command line

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, springjunit4classrunner

I have a Spring MVC project (an application framework and inversion of control container for the Java platform) with this test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:servlet.xml"
})
public class PastisControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void should_WhenParams_OK() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/user/2")
                .param("date", "01122020")
                .param("organisationId", "9")
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
..
}
```

but when I run `mvn test` from the command line, no test is executed

Comment: add the pom.xml. specifically the part relates to tests/surefire plugin. maybe you have some configuration for test class names?

Comment: If you could accept my answer that would be great...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here: `PastisControllerTests` `Test`, not `Tests`, is the name component you need for Maven to recognize it out of the box. Otherwise, you need [to override the surefire plugin's behavior](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).